# FT2232D - Device not responding to set address

Tags: usb, ftdi

I've ordered a custom planned PCB which contains an FT2232D chip.
Circuit looks like this:
[image]

**VCC** and **USB_VCC** are connected on another page.
**GND** and **USB_GND** are connected on another page.

Datasheet of FT2232D: http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT2232D.pdf
Datasheet of EEPROM: http://lomex.hu/pdf/(stm)_m93c46-m93c86.pdf

Although it seems starting upon connecting, no further steps could be done:

```
[23980.186603] usb 5-1: new full-speed USB device number 91 using xhci_hcd
[23980.277845] usb 5-1: Device not responding to set address.
[23980.569101] usb 5-1: Device not responding to set address.
[23980.769169] usb 5-1: device not accepting address 91, error -71
[23980.880898] hub 5-0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port 1
```

I'm using self powered configuration, so the chip gets its power from USB port directly.
A 6 MHz XTAL was applied, according to datasheet. And I also applied an EEPROM (although it's not a must I think).

On Windows I got unknown device and then Windows disables it because thinks it works wrong.
FT_Prog doesn't recognize it either.

On Linux the dmesg shows lines above.
Device is not responding.

How could I move on? Do you guys seen anything like this?

Comment: When you say it's almost the same it'd be worth including a schematic of what you built. I believe that part occurs very early during enumeration so it could be something wrong at a fairly low level. It doesn't sound like missing device drivers or anything similar to me.

Comment: Yes, you are right, here it is:
http://93.190.5.65/usb.png

Comment: Quarz parameters are missing.

Comment: Have you not heard of power net symbols?

Comment: Knee-jerk response would be it looks like you may not have enough decoupling. Default decoupling practice should be one 0.1 uF cap per Vcc pin, and only reduced once that's verified as working.

Comment: @TurboJ Quartz is 6MHz

Comment: @ConnorWolf Thanks for this useful tip. I didn't know that.
I think I have to reproduce the PCB to make it work. I'll let you know but it takes some time (weeks around here).

Comment: And one more thing: what else should I take care? It's very expensive to create pcb-s around here, so I'd like to make sure that it will work at this time.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the wrong pin for GND on your mini USB socket. Pin 5 is GND, pin 4 is ID and most likely *not* connected at all (in the cable).

You can try to solder bridge the pins 4 and 5 in order to get a stable ground on the USB. This should work with most cables.

EDIT: The VCC-USB_VCC connections makes this configuration **bus** powered. Thus you need to connect RESET directly to VCC without the resistor divider. See above FT2232 datasheet, schematic in chapter 6.0.

Comment: That was exactly what I've done. Without this there is no power at all on the pins of the chip. Now I'm wondering what else could I check. These FTDIs won't be my favourites for sure..

Comment: What do you think, is the layout correct? Can I measure some pins for getting more information on what's going on?

Comment: @Daniel - We can't tell you anything about your layout unless you actually post your layout.

Comment: sorry, I meant the schematic.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember if it's the very same error, but I remember similar errors when D+ and D- were switched. You might want to double check that.

Comment: It would detect a **low speed** device in this case.

Comment: I created a schematic based on this layout, and it does not showed any errors. In addition, I checked each connection if right or not on the PCB, so I'm sure D- and D+ are not switched. (Unless the layout plan above is not correct either)

Comment: But I guess D+ should connect to D+ on the other side, and D- to D- on the other side, right?

Comment: @TurboJ: Not necessarily. On Windows I got "This device cannot be started" and on Linux some similar errors (but no successful connect).

Comment: @Daniel: D+ must be connected to D+, that is correct. It is NOT like a UART RX/TX pair. Did you check all the way to your connector and from that through the cable?

Comment: @Daniel: Also, something else: Check that you do not have any stub traces on the D+/D- lines.

Comment: @TomL. If "stub trace" means vias, yes I have vias in both D+ and D- lines. Does it mean a problem? This PCB contains only 2 layers. So no stubs (I think.)

Comment: Vias should be fine, I wouldn't expect problems from that. Did you pay attention when routing the lines to the fact that D+ and D- form a differential pair and should be routed impedance matched? By Stub traces I mean that the USB signal goes to e.g. two different connectors whereas you use only one? Can you solder a cable very close to the pins of the FTDI IC (and cut the remaining trace?); Also: What part number is X1? IS R39 really necessary?

Comment: @TomL. Regarding R39: I copied everything from product datasheet, there were a resistor to USB_VCC, that's R39. I don't know if it is really neccessary or not. X1's datasheet: http://lomex.hu/pdf/(t-t)_mini_usb_5p.pdf. D+ and D- lines can't be much shorter, I can try connecting them directly somehow though.

Comment: D+ and D- are not "impedance matched", but they are the same length.

Comment: Alright, that should be ok. Can you check that you have Pins 4 and 5 on the plug connected correctly. To me it seems that pin 4 should be ID and Pin 5 should be GND.

Comment: Yes, pin4 and pin5 are shortcut, since pin5 was gnd and pin4 was nc.